# jQuery Timepicker for ASP.NET?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I've been trying to use [Jon Thornton's timepicker](https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker), but run into odd problems when using it in ASPX pages.

For example, when I am trying to do only one textbox as per this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#TextBox1').timepicker();
    });
</script>
```

It works just fine.  Everytime I click into the textbox it pops the dropdown and the selection goes into the textbox without fail.

But when I try having TWO timepickers:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#TextBox1').timepicker();
        $('#TextBox2').timepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Then I first get an error dialog which says:

> Unhandled exception at line 65, column 3427 in
>   http://localhost:1459/aa66b45d9cf7427b8b7658d9362cd16a/browserLink
>
> 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property
>   or method 'bind'

... and then comes odd behavior.

**NOTE: When running this outside of VisualStudio 2013 I don't get the JavaScript runtime error.**

If I click outside the two controls before I click on either textbox, neither one pops the timepicker.  If I click either of the controls, but don't select a time, then after that neither one pops a timepicker.  If I click on either one of the textboxes and actually select a time, then from then on they will both pop timepickers, even if I never select a time again.

VERY mystifying, and I am unsure what the javascript runtime error has to do with it, nor what causes it.

Comment: What sort of problems?

Comment: @matt_lethargic I added some detail and description

Comment: Cool. Are you running this in visual studio? It looks like you have browser link enabled and its that that is throwing the exception. Just a thought

Comment: Yes, @matt_lethargic, it is running in VS2013.  I will sound ignorant, but what is "browser link" and how do you disable it if this will help?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx. Don't know if it'll help, but it will remove one unknown.

Comment: @matt_lethargic - after you asked if I were running this in VS, I prepared a Release version and promoted it to one of our web servers.  Where I get the same behavior that I get in VS.  Hmmm.  I will check out the MSDN link you provided.

Comment: I'm surprised even the first version works seeing as you haven't added `ClientIDMode="Static"` to the textbox(es).

Comment: That was my next suggestion!

Comment: @sh1rts, adding Static ClientIDMode doesn't help.  If that were a problem, it wouldn't work at all.